# drupal 7 wildcard and parameter replacement?

Tags: 7

How can i use _load() function in drupal 7 ? Please look at this one.

```
function sample_menu() {
  $items['node/%hotel_node/images'] = array(
    'title' => 'Images',
    'weight' => -10,
    'page callback' => 'show_tab_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 'images'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array(1),
  );
  return $items;
}

function hotel_node_load($nid)  {
  //$node = node_load($nid);
  $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid));
  return $node;      
}

function show_tab_page($s1='',$s2='') {
  return('s1 is @s1 with $s1 @s2 with $s2',array('@s1' => $s1,'@s2' => $s2));
}
```

while trying in the url : http://localhost/drupal/user/2337/images

**Am getting Page not found
The requested page "/drupal/node/232/images" could not be found.**

Please help me out. thanks

Comment: I am not clear why, if you are looking at http://localhost/drupal/user/2337/images, you are getting an error about drupal/node/232/images. The code you are showing is for node/%/images, not user/%/images.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some disparity in your naming conventions here. Your functions should be named with `MODULENAME_` as a prefix, including all hooks that you implement.

For example, if your module is called 'sample' then as well as the folder the module files are in being called 'sample', your files will need to be named similarly (sample.info, sample.module, etc.). If you don't follow this convention your hooks won't be called; and it's just good practice to prefix your module's functions with the module name.

The other thing here is that you don't actually *need* to use your own router load function...the node module has already done it for you (with the `node_load()` function). You can simply re-use that:

```
function sample_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/images'] = array(
    'title' => 'Images',
    'weight' => -10,
    'page callback' => 'sample_show_tab_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 'images'),
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );
  return $items;
}
```

You should be aware that `node_load()` returns a node object, so the first parameter to your page callback function will be that object. The second will be the string 'images', as per the arguments you've provided in `page arguments`.

Your page callback (which I've renamed :P) would then look more like this:

```
function sample_show_tab_page($node, $arg1) {
  // Use whatever you need from the node object
  $nid = $node->nid;
  $title = $node->title;
  // etc...
}
```

Finally, and perhaps most importantly to commit to memory, make sure you clear Drupal's caches once you've added/edited any hook. Such implementations are cached, and the system won't pick up these changes until you tell it to.

Comment: hi, i need to replace % in the drupal path with the parameter like user_uid_optional_load('2345').How can i use this ??

Comment: Sorry I'm not really sure what you mean

Comment: from pro.development, under menu system they have given a topic "Wildcards and Parameter replacement'. I don't understand to work on this. could you please explain me that

Comment: It's quite a big topic...your best bet would be to read the [`hook_menu()` docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) which go into quite a lot of detail about load arguments

Answer (score 1):

The code as it is written doesn't work because you are passing the wrong parameter to [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7): In Drupal 7, the function needs:

- the node ID
- (optionally) the revision ID
- (optionally) a flag to reset the cache used from the load function

Also the node ID is optional, but you generally call the function to get a node.

The parameters you are using are the ones required from Drupal 6, although it is possible to pass the node ID to the function, instead of an array, as the function executes the following code:

```
  $cachable = ($revision == NULL);
  $arguments = array();
  if (is_numeric($param)) {
    if ($cachable) {
      // Is the node statically cached?
      if (isset($nodes[$param])) {
        return is_object($nodes[$param]) ? drupal_clone($nodes[$param]) : $nodes[$param];
      }
    }
    $cond = 'n.nid = %d';
    $arguments[] = $param;
  }
```

If the first parameter is not an array, it is considered the node ID.

As already said from Clive, there is not need to use such a load function that just calls `node_load()`; you just need to use the appropriate wildcard argument, which (in this case) is "%node"; replace it to the menu path, and you get *node/%node/images*. Clearly, it makes sense to use a custom load function if, for example, you need to check the content type of the returned node; `node_load()` returns the node object for every object.

```
function sample_menu() {
  $items['node/%sample_hotel/images'] = array(
    'title' => 'Images',
    'weight' => -10,
    'page callback' => 'sample_images_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 'images'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function sample_hotel_load($nid)  {
  $node = node_load($nid);

  if (!empty($node) && ($info = node_type_get_type($node)) && ($info->type == 'hotel')) {
    return $node;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

To what already said from Clive, I would add that the code of `show_tab_page()`, although I understand it's debugging code, it doesn't make sense. It is probable you are trying to call `t()`, and in that case your function should be the following one:

```
function show_tab_page($s1 = '', $s2 = '') {
  return t('s1 is @s1; s2 is @s2', array('@s1' => $s1,'@s2' => $s2));
}
```

The code you are wrote causes a parse error. The `return` statement is expecting a single value, which could be:

- the value returned from a function
- the value of a variable
- a string literal
- an array
- an integer
- a constant

In any cases, `return` is not expecting two values separated from a comma; that is the reason of the parse error.

If that is debugging code, there is no need to use `t()`, as debugging code doesn't need to be translated; if you just want to be able to replace parameters in a string as `t()` does, you should use code similar to the following one.

```
function show_tab_page($s1 = '', $s2 = '') {
  return format_string('s1 is @s1; s2 is @s2', array('@s1' => $s1,'@s2' => $s2));
}
```